# Update details to database through PHP insert/update and echo the same in another page without refreshing the page

Tags: php, mysqli

I Have a php page which interact with DB to insert or update the details given in to the table.

In user php page, user enters his details and so, when click on update, it leads to update php page, where it updates the details and then redirects to the same page. But after it redirects to the user page, it doesn't echo the inserted/updated details until i refresh the page.

the code goes as:

User page:

```
 <div class="col-sm-7 mgbt-xs-20">
    <h3 class="mgbt-xs-15 font-semibold"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o mgr-10 profile-icon"></i> ROOM BASIC DETAILS</h3>
      <div class="content-list content-menu">
         <ul class="list-wrapper">
            <li class="mgbt-xs-10"> <span class="menu-icon vd_green"><i class="fa  fa-circle-o"></i></span> \
              <span class="menu-text"> <a style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo ($row2['name']); ?></a> 
                at <a style="font-size:15px;" ><?php echo ($row2['location']); ?></a> 
                 <span class="menu-info"><span class="menu-date" style="font-size:15px;"> <?php echo ($row2['type']); ?></span><br>
                    <span class="menu-date" style="font-size:15px;"> <?php echo ($row2['star']); ?> Star </span></span> </span> 
             </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
```

PHP Page:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$star = $_POST['star'];

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE rooms SET name = '$name', location = '$location', type = '$type', star = '$star'
WHERE email = '$email'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Details have been Updated")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="user.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Now as i told, the updated details won't show until i refresh the user page after it gets redirected from php page.

Please don't worry about the DB  connection  in php page, which  i have n't mentioned in PHP code.

Any suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: You could use `header('Location: user.php')` to redirect, much shorter

Comment: Are you posting the form to the same page? and where is the select query?

Comment: @manian don't worry about the select query, it is there, i just didn't added into the question. And after inserting the data into db, it will redirect to the same user page, where it should get the data from the db.

Comment: It depends on where you have these queries. So, you have update query in update php file & select query in user php file, right? Also, your form is in user php & you are submitting it to update php file, right?

Comment: exactly @manian

Comment: I think, I am posting too many questions. I dont see code for redirection in your update code block. how did you redirect it back from update php file to user php file?

Comment: like this `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Details have been Updated")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="user.php"></a>';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142562/discussion-between-manian-and-harishk).

Answer (score 0):

I did not see your code but I assumed that you placed your update query below the select query.

Please move the code block of Update Query above the code block of Select Query.

In others words update should happen before your select query so that it fetches updated data. Otherwise, your select query will fetch data before updating & hence you need to refresh the page to see the updated data.

It should be like in the below order,

```
<?php
  include "dbconnection.php";
  include "update.php";

  //Perform Your select query here,
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE [YOUR CONDITION]";
  mysqli_query($con,$query); 
?>

  <!-- Your form goes here -->
 <form>
   <!-- submit this form to update user information -->
 </form>
```

Comment: ah ok. is it possible to post your full code, at-least like a structure in the answer here?